# CORS preflight request not handled by external API

Tags: javascript, api, axios, frontend

I'm trying to create front-end application for [getresponse.com](https://getresponse.com). It has own API which located at https://api.getresponse.com. When I'm trying to do any javascript request form browser with Axios or Fetch I've got this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.getresponse.com/v3/accounts' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

And in the network tab I have:

```
Request URL: https://api.getresponse.com/v3/accounts
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
```

So, as far as I can understand with API can't work with 'complex' requests from web browser properly.

Now I've got only one idea - to make some middleware, which will proxy my requests to API endpoints without any pre-flight requests.

Am I right? I can't find any examples of such a middleware. Where can I find any information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James answer is ok, but right now I'm more comfortable with solution based on Node.js rather than Nginx, as I developing locally on windows.
I came up to the solutions with Express server:

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy'); 

app.use(cors())

app.use('/', proxy('https://api.getresponse.com'))

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Answer (score 3):

> A CORS preflight request is a CORS request that checks to see if the
>   CORS protocol is understood and a server is aware using specific
>   methods and headers.

More details on the preflight request can be found [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

You should probably look into how to handle [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) on your server. For all the request you make from the javascript will be validated by the browser. So, your server should respond with the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` read more about the [header here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

By inspecting from browser network tab you should be able to view the headers which are present in your response.

As you do not have control on the `API` server, you can create a [proxy server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling) to communicate with the external servers. You can find a detailed [tutorial here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-18-04-server).

Here is an example nginx vhost configuration which handles a proxy for all requests with `/api` to `https://api.example.com`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;   # Your server domain, in your case localhost
    location /api {
      access_log off;
      proxy_pass https://api.example.com;  # <--- this will the target domain
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

So, if you make `http://example.com/api/v3/accounts`, this will be forwarded to `https://api.example.com/api/v3/accounts`.

Basically you should have the below headers in your response.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://yourdomain.com
```

You can also have below configuration.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

If you use [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) then you cannot use the wildcard `*` for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, you should explicitly mention the domain.

Comment: Thanks for answer, James!
But it is only general information.
Are you talking about the server which will be the middleware?

Comment: @Justice47 First of all your server should allow the `OPTIONS` requests. Can you share what framework your are using for your backend?

Comment: Please read my question again - I'm not using any framework, I'm even haven't got any backend part of my application.
API is supported by external service.

Comment: First you should understand how the Cross orgin requests works. If you do not have  control on handling the response headers. You should contact the provider. Whatever I've metioned in the answer are the resons why you are getting the issue.

Comment: However, you can create a proxy server which you have the full controll and through which you can communicate with provder APIs.

Comment: Thanks, I have understanding of CORS and it's preflight requests, mainly from this article - http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/
I'm also thinking about proxy server of some kind. Maybe there is any  node.js open source server which is pre-configured for this kind of tasks?

Comment: You don't need `nodejs` for this. You can easily create/configure the proxy server with `apache` or `nginx`. I've updated the answer with a tutorial link.