# Download Image Using Fetch In ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to download an image using fetch in reactJS. But whenever I call the function, I face the CORS error.

```
            var image_trade_license = new Image();
            image_trade_license.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
            image_trade_license.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952";
            // get file name - you might need to modify this if your image url doesn't contain a file extension otherwise you can set the file name manually
            var fileName_trade_license = 'trade_license';
            image_trade_license.onload = function () {
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.width = this.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
                canvas.height = this.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size
                canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                var blob_trade_license;
                // ... get as Data URI
                if (image_trade_license.src.indexOf(".jpg") > -1) {
                blob_trade_license = canvas.toDataURL("image_trade_license/jpeg");
                } else if (image_trade_license.src.indexOf(".png") > -1) {
                blob_trade_license = canvas.toDataURL("image_trade_license/png");
                } else if (image_trade_license.src.indexOf(".gif") > -1) {
                blob_trade_license = canvas.toDataURL("image_trade_license/gif");
                } else {
                blob_trade_license = canvas.toDataURL("image_trade_license/png");
                }
                $("#image1").append("<a download='" + fileName_trade_license + "' href='" + blob_trade_license + "'><button>Download Trade License</button></a>");
            }
```

and I am facing this error (occured in browser Console) -

```
Access to image at 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952' from origin 
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control- 
Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
via.placeholder.com/150/92c952:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58077982/cors-preflight-request-not-handled-by-external-api/58078124#58078124

Comment: try to do smth like that `fetch('https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952', {method: 'GET', mode: 'no-cors'}).then(resp => console.log('test'))`

Comment: Cors error is usually the issue of back-end. Please ask your back-end developer to insert cors code. For express.js back-end, you can refer to this page: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak I tried this but I am still not getting proper output.

Answer (score 0):

First, Have you ever set `mode: "no-cors"` in fetch config? Like this:

```
fetch('https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: "no-cors"
})
```

If you still receive CORS error. You can disable origin policy in Chrome to continue to call API that without CORS error with [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Or, [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-pr) could give you more knowledge about CORS in Web Browser.